# Refactor Name in MongoDB Document

Tags: mongodb

In my current mongo collection my objects are stored such as

```
{
    _id: '....',
    name: 'Thomas Jefferson',
    date: '12/1/2016'
}
```

Some are stored such as

```
{
    _id: '....',
    name: 'FRANKLIN, BENJAMIN',
    date: '12/1/2016'
}
```

But now I must rewrite/refactor my documents so that they are of the format

```
{
    _id: '....',
    name: {
        first: 'BENJAMIN',
        last: 'FRANKLIN'
    },
    date: '12/1/2016'
},
{
    _id: '....',
    name: {
        first: 'Thomas',
        last: 'Jefferson'
    },
    date: '12/1/2016'
}
```

I know there's not a single command I can accomplish both cases with but is there one in which I can accomplish the *LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME* case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it with `find().foreach` in the shell.

**Before**

```
db.users.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58ffc291055ee5ec5334d97b"),
        "name" : "FRANKLIN, BENJAMIN",
        "date" : "12/1/2016"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58ffc298055ee5ec5334d97c"),
        "name" : "Thomas Jefferson",
        "date" : "12/1/2016"
}
```

**Query**

```
// {name: {$type: 'string'}} will filter on records with name of type string
db.users.find({name: {$type: 'string'}}).forEach(function(item) {
  if (item.name) {
    var lastname = item.name.split(' ')[0].replace(',', '');
    var firstname = item.name.split(' ')[1];
    db.users.update(
      {_id: item._id}, 
      {$set: {lastname: lastname, firstname: firstname}}
    )
  }
})
```

**After**

```
db.users.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58ffc291055ee5ec5334d97b"),
        "name" : "FRANKLIN, BENJAMIN",
        "date" : "12/1/2016",
        "lastname" : "FRANKLIN",
        "firstname" : "BENJAMIN"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58ffc298055ee5ec5334d97c"),
        "name" : "Thomas Jefferson",
        "date" : "12/1/2016",
        "lastname" : "Thomas",
        "firstname" : "Jefferson"
}
```

Comment: `item.name.split is not a function`, mongodb v3.2.6

Comment: I've just tried on a 3.2.6 mongo, it should work, I think that you have record(s) with `name: null`. I updated the query with a guard clause to protect you from this specific case.

Comment: No...no instance where I have null names. Here's the error verbatim: `2017-04-25T14:58:15.472-0700 E QUERY    [thread1] TypeError: item.name.split is not a function :
@(shell):1:83
DBQuery.prototype.forEach@src/mongo/shell/query.js:488:1
@(shell):1:1`

Comment: @gh0st : Is your name attribute always a string ?

Comment: Yes, but is there a way I can double check?

Comment: @gh0st an easy way is to change `if (item.name) {` from the answer to `if (item.name && item.name.split) {`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142665/discussion-between-julien-tassin-and-gh0st).